# sql exception:Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

I wrote the following method to execute update statement inside the database:

```
 public boolean updateEmployee(int id){
    try {
        String update="UPDATE employee set name='updatedName' and address='updatedaddress' where id=(?)";
        pst=connection.prepareStatement(update);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

But the following exception occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

And this exception is also thrown:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'UpdatedName'
```

What's the problem here? In addition, how can I return the result of an update statement (since `executeQuery` doesn't work with DML Statements)?

Comment: Why are you using this "id=(?)"? Just "id=?" is not enough?

I'm not saying that this is wrong, ok? It's because I can't remember about parameters in JDBC PreparedStatements. From what I remember, the parentheses is not necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but perhaps the statement should be

```
UPDATE employee set name='updatedName' , address='updatedaddress' where id=(?)
```

instead of

`UPDATE employee set name='updatedName' and address='updatedaddress' where id=(?)`

`and` should be used only in the where clause.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like an unclosed quote issue ?

```
name='updatedname and address
```

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'updatedname'

Comment: @Eslam.. Check the type of `name` column in database. I suspect you set it as Double. It should be Varchar.

Comment: the type of the column does not match the value type you are trying to insert, String to Double perhaps ?

Comment: I SWEAR THAT I'AM SETTING BOTH NAME AND ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(45)